# Javascript validation. What am I not passing after the .val using values

Tags: javascript, ajax

how is my values not passing for ajax using trim and val. The issue is that when I check it using trim and val the values get check if there was anything typed if there is nothing then it sends to validation false if there is something it will hide the validate. All works bu the values do not make it and I get a new row without values. What am I missing from my function to pass my values. Here is the code:

```
    var validation = "";
var values = {};
if ($.trim($("#name").val()) === "") {
    $("#validateName").show();
    validation = "false";
} else {
    $("#validateName").hide();
}
if ($.trim($("#news").val()) === "") {
    $("#validateNews").show();
    validation = "false";
} else {
    $("#validateNews").hide();  
}   
if(validation == "false"){
    return false;
}   
values['addnews'] = '';
$.ajax({
       //  Rest of the code //
```

This is how it was previously passed. Here is the code:

```
    $.each($('#add-news-form').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
    if((field.value == 0)){
        validation = "false";
    }
    values[field.name] = field.value;
    });
```

What am I missing from my ajax function to pass the values?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to ask. Can you please explain more ?

Comment: I recommend *not* using `""` and `"false"` to represent boolean state.

Comment: Hmm hard to tell without seeing exactly what you're passing but try changing the === to ==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assign the name input text to the values object, you can do it like so:

```
values['name'] = $.trim($("#name").val());
```

Ideally you shouldn't have this trim statement twice, you should store the trimmed value in a variable and use that variable in both your validation and assignment sections.

Then make sure you're passing 'values' in the data param of your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  data: values
  // rest of your ajax code
});
```